# Error with char parameter methods Arduino Code

Tags: arduino

I keep getting the following error message when I'm trying to run my code. I can not figure out how to correct these errors so I can test everything. Even though these are just warning messages and the code says it uploads. I don't get any messages on my serial monitor printing any statements.

Code:

```
#include <Wire.h> 
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x3F,16,2);  // set the LCD address for a 16 chars and 2 line display

const int guessPin = 7;

const int switch0Pin =  13;
const int switch1Pin =  12;
const int switch2Pin =  11;
const int switch3Pin =  10;
const int switch4Pin =  9;

int currentLetterIndex = 0;
int currentClueIndex = 0;
int currentGuess = 0;
int lastGuess = 0;

bool debug = false; // set to false to turn off serial output

unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
long restInterval = 20 * 1000; // 20 second time out to conserve battery

char clueBreak[] = "Get clue at the next house :)";
char hintBreak[] = "ah ah ah... must be patient";
char answerBreak[] = "santa";

char clue1[] = "The place we first meet?";
char hint1[] = "Company... not city";
char answer1[] = "pcc";

char clue2[] = "The play we saw in NY";
char hint2[] = "muppets... no...";
char answer2[] = "avenueq";

char clue3[] = "What we worn in Times Square";
char hint3[] = "look me in the eyes...";
char answer3[] = "diapers";

char clue4[] = "Where I said 'I Love You'";
char hint4[] = "And you later threw up on me...";
char answer4[] = "tonys";

char clue5[] = "";
char hint5[] = "+++ ++ ++++ ++++";
char answer5[] = "";

char clue6[] = "When do we do anything?";
char hint6[] = "'bye' 'see you +++++++'";
char answer6[] = "maybe tomorrow";

char clue7[] = "The animal you pet in gatlinburg";
char hint7[] = "spell the numbers...";
char answer7[] = "jellyfish";

char clue8[] = "These are only in California";
char hint8[] = "the one you used to sleep with";
char answer8[] = "seven eleven";

char clue9[] = "Where did you buy your cat?";
char hint9[] = "(-_-)  R-O-B-O-T";
char answer9[] = "japan";

char clue10[] = "The ugliest car color...";
char hint10[] = "your second favorite color";
char answer10[] = "yellow";

char clue11[] = "Our first wine and paint";
char hint11[] = "__ _____ _____";
char answer11[] = "no drama llama";

const int cluesNum = 10; // clues + breaks

char * hints[] = {
  hint1,
  hint2,
  hint3,
  hint4,
  hint5,
  hint6,
  hint7,
  hint8,
  hint9,
  hint10,
  hint11,
};

char * clues[] = {
  clue1,
  clue2,
  clue3,
  clue4,
  clue5,
  clue6,
  clue7,
  clue8,
  clue9,
  clue10,
  clue11,
};

char * answers[] = {
  answer1,
  answer2,
  answer3,
  answer4,
  answer5,
  answer6,
  answer7,
  answer8,
  answer9,
  answer10,
  answer11,
};

char currentLine1[17]; // need extra char for null pointer
char currentLine2[17]; // need extra char for null pointer
bool isDisplayingClue = true;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(guessPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(switch0Pin, INPUT);
  pinMode(switch1Pin, INPUT);
  pinMode(switch2Pin, INPUT);
  pinMode(switch3Pin, INPUT);
  pinMode(switch4Pin, INPUT);

  lcd.init();
  lcd.backlight();
  if (debug)
  {
    Serial.begin(9600);
  }
}

void updateDisplayFromArray(const char *str)
{
  int limit = getCharSize(str)-1;
  for (int i = 0; i >= 16; i++)
  {
    if (i <= limit)
    {
      currentLine1[i] = str[i];
    }
    if (i+16 <= limit)
    {
      currentLine2[i] = str[i+16];
    }
  }
}

int getCharSize(const char *cArray)
{
  return sizeof(cArray) / sizeof(char);
}

void logger(const char *message)
{
  if (debug)
  {
    Serial.println(message);
  }
}

void restLCD()
{  
  lcd.setBacklight(0);
  lcd.noDisplay();
}

void showLCD()
{  
  isDisplayingClue = false;
  previousMillis = millis();
  lcd.setBacklight(50);
  lcd.display();
}

void TypeAnimation(const char *line1, const char *line2, int delayTime)
{
  lcd.clear();  
  for (int i = 0; i <= getCharSize(line1)-1; i++) {
    lcd.setCursor(i,0);
    lcd.print(line1[i]);
    delay(delayTime);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i <= getCharSize(line2)-1; i++) {
    lcd.setCursor(i,1);
    lcd.print(line2[i]);
    delay(delayTime);
    if (i == getCharSize(line2)-1) {
      delay(1000);
    }
  }
}

void DelayAnimation(const char *line1, const char *line2, int delayTime)
{
  setScreen(line1, line2);
  delay(delayTime);
}

void setScreen(const char *line1, const char *line2) 
{ 
  lcd.clear(); 
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print(line1);
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print(line2);  
}

void TestAnimations()
{ 
  showLCD();
  PlayGuessingAnimation();
  PlayCorrectAnimation();
  PlayIncorrectAnimation();
  ResetClues();
  CurrentStatus();
  ShowCurrentGuess();
  DisplayClue(5000);
  restLCD();
  delay(5000);  
  currentLetterIndex++;  
}

void ResetClues() 
{  
  DelayAnimation("Resetting...", "",1500);
  DelayAnimation("Merry Christmas!", "My Love :)",4000);
  TypeAnimation("Old Man Turtle", "has been taken",250);
  TypeAnimation("again...", ":(",250);
  TypeAnimation("Solve the clues", "to find him",250);
  TypeAnimation("Use the button 2", "submit da letter",250);
  DelayAnimation("Now for your 1st", "clue",4000);
  TypeAnimation("Goodluck my love", ":)",250);
  NextClue();
  currentLetterIndex = 0;
  currentClueIndex = 0;  
}

void ShowFinalAnimation()
{
  TypeAnimation("You did it!", "",250);
  TypeAnimation("You saved", "Old Man Turtle",250);
  TypeAnimation("Old Man Turtle", "has left yo",250);
  TypeAnimation("Use the button 2", "submit da letter",250);
  DelayAnimation("Now for your 1st", "clue",4000);
  TypeAnimation("Goodluck my love", ":)",250);
}

void loop()
{
  logger("************* NEW LOOP *************");
  //PlayGuessingGame();
  TestAnimations();
}

void PlayGuessingGame()
{
  bool buttonState = digitalRead(guessPin);  
  char *state = char(buttonState);
  logger(state);
  ConvertGuess();
  if (buttonState)
  {
    logger("made it inside button guess clicked");
    showLCD();
    CheckGuess();
  }
  else
  {
    if (lastGuess != currentGuess)
    {
      logger("The guess has changed");
      showLCD();   
      ShowCurrentGuess();   
      lastGuess = currentGuess;
    }
    else
    {
      logger("The guess hasn't changed :(");
      if (!isDisplayingClue)
      {
        DisplayClue(1);
      }
      unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
      if(currentMillis - previousMillis > restInterval * .7) 
      {
        DelayAnimation(" About to enter ", "-- Rest  Mode --",1500);
      }
      if(currentMillis - previousMillis > restInterval) 
      {
        logger("...REST MODE ACTIVATED...");
        restLCD();
      }
    }
  }
  if (currentClueIndex > cluesNum)
  {
    ShowFinalAnimation();
  }
}

void ConvertGuess()
{
  bitWrite(currentGuess,0, !digitalRead(switch0Pin));
  bitWrite(currentGuess,1, !digitalRead(switch1Pin));
  bitWrite(currentGuess,2, !digitalRead(switch2Pin));
  bitWrite(currentGuess,3, !digitalRead(switch3Pin));
  bitWrite(currentGuess,4, !digitalRead(switch4Pin));
  logger("Beginning conversion of guess");
  logger("Pin 0:" + char(!digitalRead(switch0Pin)));
  logger("Pin 1:" + char(!digitalRead(switch1Pin)));
  logger("Pin 2:" + char(!digitalRead(switch2Pin)));
  logger("Pin 3:" + char(!digitalRead(switch3Pin)));
  logger("Pin 4:" + char(!digitalRead(switch4Pin)));
  logger("new guess is " + char(ConvertIntToLetter(currentGuess)));
}

void CheckGuess()
{
  PlayGuessingAnimation();
  char guessLetter = ConvertIntToLetter(currentGuess);
  char cLetter = clues[currentClueIndex][currentLetterIndex];
  if (guessLetter == '-')
  {
    ResetClues();
  }
  else if (guessLetter == '+')
  {
    CurrentStatus();
  }
  else if (guessLetter == '?')
  {
    DisplayHint(5000);
  }
  else if (guessLetter == cLetter)
  {
    currentLetterIndex++;
    if (currentLetterIndex > getCharSize(clues[currentClueIndex])-1)
    {
      PlayNextClueAnimation();
      currentLetterIndex = 0;
      currentClueIndex++;
    }
    PlayCorrectAnimation();
  }
  else
  {
    PlayIncorrectAnimation();
  }
}

void ShowCurrentGuess() 
{  
  char guess = char(ConvertIntToLetter(currentGuess));
  if (guess == '-')
  {
    DelayAnimation("   DANGER!!!   ", "THIS WILL RESET!",5000);
    DelayAnimation("Press the button", "will reset",2000);
  }
  else if (guess == '+')
  {    
    DelayAnimation("This will", "Show current status",2000);
  }
  else if (guess == '?')
  {    
    DelayAnimation("This will", "Show you a hint",2000);
  }
  else if (guess == ' ')
  {    
    DelayAnimation("You're Guessing ", "'_' (space)",1500);
  }
  else
  {
    DelayAnimation("You're Guessing ", char(guess),1500);
  }
}

void CurrentStatus()
{  
  char currentAnswer[17] = "";
  if (currentLetterIndex == 0)
  {
    strcpy(currentAnswer, "nothing yet :(");
  }
  else
  {
    strcpy(currentAnswer, GetCorrectGuesses());
  }
  DelayAnimation("You've Guessed ", strcat(char(currentClueIndex), " Clues"), 2000);
  DelayAnimation("The Current", "Clues Is...", 2000);
  DisplayClue(2000);
  DelayAnimation("You've got right", currentAnswer, 3000);
}

char GetCorrectGuesses()
{
  char result[17];
  for(int i = 0; i >= currentLetterIndex; i++)
  {
    result[i] = answers[currentClueIndex][i];
  }
  return result;
}

void DisplayClue(int delayTime)
{
  updateDisplayFromArray(clues[currentClueIndex]);
  DelayAnimation(currentLine1,currentLine1,delayTime);
  isDisplayingClue = true;
}

void DisplayHint(int delayTime)
{
  updateDisplayFromArray(hints[currentClueIndex]);
  TypeAnimation(currentLine1,currentLine1,delayTime);
}

void NextClue()
{  
  DelayAnimation(" Are you ready?? ", " Clue #" + char(currentClueIndex+1),3000);
  DisplayClue(5000);
}

void PlayGuessingAnimation()
{
  TypeAnimation("That is...", "",200);
}

void PlayNextClueAnimation()
{
  TypeAnimation("HOORAY!!!", "",200);
  DelayAnimation("You Got It Right", "   Go You ;)   ",2000);
  TypeAnimation("On to the next", "",200);
  NextClue();
}

void PlayCorrectAnimation()
{
  DelayAnimation("   CORRECT!!!!  ", "",1500);
}

void PlayIncorrectAnimation()
{
  DelayAnimation("    Wrong :(    ", "   Try Again   ",2000);
}

char ConvertIntToLetter(int number)
{
  int result = '0';
  switch (number)
  {
    case 0:
      result = 'a';
      break;
    case 1:
      result = 'b';
      break;
    case 2:
      result = 'c';
      break;
    case 3:
      result = 'd';
      break;
    case 4:
      result = 'e';
      break;
    case 5:
      result = 'f';
      break;
    case 6:
      result = 'g';
      break;
    case 7:
      result = 'h';
      break;
    case 8:
      result = 'i';
      break;
    case 9:
      result = 'j';
      break;
    case 10:
      result = 'k';
      break;
    case 11:
      result = 'l';
      break;
    case 12:
      result = 'm';
      break;
    case 13:
      result = 'n';
      break;
    case 14:
      result = 'o';
      break;
    case 15:
      result = 'p';
      break;
    case 16:
      result = 'q';
      break;
    case 17:
      result = 'r';
      break;
    case 18:
      result = 's';
      break;
    case 19:
      result = 't';
      break;
    case 20:
      result = 'u';
      break;
    case 21:
      result = 'v';
      break;
    case 22:
      result = 'w';
      break;
    case 23:
      result = 'x';
      break;
    case 24:
      result = 'y';
      break;
    case 25:
      result = 'z';
      break;
    case 26:
      result = '!';
      break;
    case 27:
      result = '%';
      break;
    case 28:
      result = ' ';
      break;
    case 29:
      result = '?';
      break;
    case 30:
      result = '-';
      break;
    case 31:
      result = '+';
  }
  return result;
}
```

Error Messages:

```
C:\Users\jb090\Documents\Arduino\ChristmasBoxV3\ChristmasBoxV3.ino: In function 'void PlayGuessingGame()':

C:\Users\jb090\Documents\Arduino\ChristmasBoxV3\ChristmasBoxV3.ino:263:17: warning: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]

   char *state = char(buttonState);

                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

C:\Users\jb090\Documents\Arduino\ChristmasBoxV3\ChristmasBoxV3.ino: In function 'void ShowCurrentGuess()':

C:\Users\jb090\Documents\Arduino\ChristmasBoxV3\ChristmasBoxV3.ino:378:40: warning: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]

     DelayAnimation("You're Guessing ", char(guess),1500);

                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~

C:\Users\jb090\Documents\Arduino\ChristmasBoxV3\ChristmasBoxV3.ino:198:6: note:   initializing argument 2 of 'void DelayAnimation(const char*, const char*, int)'

 void DelayAnimation(const char *line1, const char *line2, int delayTime)

      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~

C:\Users\jb090\Documents\Arduino\ChristmasBoxV3\ChristmasBoxV3.ino: In function 'void CurrentStatus()':

C:\Users\jb090\Documents\Arduino\ChristmasBoxV3\ChristmasBoxV3.ino:391:44: warning: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]

     strcpy(currentAnswer, GetCorrectGuesses());

                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~

In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Arduino.h:25:0,

                 from sketch\ChristmasBoxV3.ino.cpp:1:

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\string.h:305:14: note:   initializing argument 2 of 'char* strcpy(char*, const char*)'

 extern char *strcpy(char *, const char *);

              ^~~~~~

C:\Users\jb090\Documents\Arduino\ChristmasBoxV3\ChristmasBoxV3.ino:393:44: warning: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]

   DelayAnimation("You've Guessed ", strcat(char(currentClueIndex), " Clues"), 2000);

                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Arduino.h:25:0,

                 from sketch\ChristmasBoxV3.ino.cpp:1:

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\string.h:248:14: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'char* strcat(char*, const char*)'

 extern char *strcat(char *, const char *);

              ^~~~~~

C:\Users\jb090\Documents\Arduino\ChristmasBoxV3\ChristmasBoxV3.ino: In function 'char GetCorrectGuesses()':

C:\Users\jb090\Documents\Arduino\ChristmasBoxV3\ChristmasBoxV3.ino:406:10: warning: invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]

   return result;

          ^~~~~~

C:\Users\jb090\Documents\Arduino\ChristmasBoxV3\ChristmasBoxV3.ino:401:8: warning: address of local variable 'result' returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]

   char result[17];

        ^~~~~~
```

Comment: you have to much wrong in this sketch. write some small test sketches to try out simple things.

Comment: This aren't actually errors. At least the messages you posted are just warnings and notes. However, review them carefully - some might indicate that your code won't work as you expect or the program will crash at runtime.

Comment: I had a sketch that worked completely fine before but I used all "String" data types for my arrays declared at the beginning. I need to save on memory so I'm trying to convert to "Char". Everything in my code worked before then

Comment: @Alfageme Thank you for the comment. So you are saying that I'm probably having a runtime issue? I suppose that makes sense since the code does say it uploads to the arduino successfully at the end. So this could cause my serial output to not function as well?

Answer (score 1):

`char` and `char*` is very different !

`const char*` can be slightly more tricky, but you first have to get the difference between a text and a character.

"Hello World" is a text, and usually treated as a pointer or [const] array.

'A' is a character, and internally stored the same way as the number 65 in a variable of type `char`.

More:

c# (or java) and c++ are very different, too. And there's a lot of truth in the saying "c++ is for masochists"  :)

Your first problem

> warning: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char*'
>
> char *state = char(buttonState);

comes from these lines:

```
bool buttonState = digitalRead(guessPin);  
char *state = char(buttonState);
logger(state);
```

`logger(const char*)` needs a text to log, but you have a bool. Not sure how you wrote that in c#, and casting won't help. You eventually might want something like

```
bool buttonState = digitalRead(guessPin);  
logger(buttonState? "guessPin is set": "guessPin is LOW");
```

Comment: Coming from c#...I find Arduino a "bit" of a challenge at times!

Comment: @ChrisCatignani I fully agree! all of the low level stuff like pointers and references get taken care of behind the scene. After messing with some things I believe I messed up a couple of the "FOR" loops here which ended up trying to write more data to the char array then I had specified... and that ended up sending a very strange byte array to the LCD screen which then changed the address so they weren't able to communicate with each other. Long story short, I should stick to C# for less headaches lol

Comment: Also the "getCharSize" function I made was wrong and I needed to use "strlen()" and for whatever reason the 9600 baud messed with my LCD output and worked correctly when I moved to 115200

Comment: If Serial speed matters, there's something else wrong. Regarding your comment about C#, I added a bit to my response.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast a variable as a char by doing `char(buttonState)`. In C you cast as follows: `(char)buttonState`.

Comment: I was surprised to find that the functional syntax char(buttonState) is now allowed in C++, and Arduino's C++ compiler. See "Functional Cast" https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast

Answer (score 0):

There were some minor errors in my code (like incorrect for loop syntax) that was causing me to have run time errors.